# finding position of duplicate entry in array and changing only the second duplicate

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have an array like so:

```
array('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field2', 'field4', 'field1', 'field2');
```

What I would like to do is to find any duplicate values and change the second (and further) duplicate entries like so:

```
array('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field2_2', 'field4', 'field1_2', 'field2_3');
```

Is there a function in PHP that returns the key of the duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to find all the keys in an array which have a given value and then iterate over those entries (other than the first), adding a counter to the value:

```
$array = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field2', 'field4', 'field1', 'field2');
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $keys = array_keys($array, $value);
    // get rid of the first entry
    array_shift($keys);
    // add counters to duplicates
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
        $array[$keys[$i]] = $value . "_" . ($i + 2);
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => field1
    [1] => field2
    [2] => field3
    [3] => field2_2
    [4] => field4
    [5] => field1_2
    [6] => field2_3
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9tKJS)